# gcc gdb building - "lvalue required as increment operand" on *((void **)__o->next_free)++ = ((void *)datum);

Tags: c, gcc, lvalue

Trying to build the gdb package but it errors out at obstack.h with the error message

```
lvalue required as increment operand
```

Going to the location of the error gives this line of code

```
*((void **)__o->next_free)++ = ((void *)datum);
```

Can anyone explain why the error message is occurring and what should be done?

I used to think I knew the C language in and out but guess not.

From the same code source, just a few lines above the following line appears to compile without error:

```
*(__o->next_free)++ = 0;
```

They appear the same?

Comment: They appear the same except for the part that's not the same: a `(void**)` cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you perform a cast on the expression that is being incremented.  The C99 standard says this in a footnote:

> A cast does not yield an lvalue

And the post-increment operator requires an lvalue.

Note that due to operator precedence rules, the expression is equivalent to:

```
*(((void **)__o->next_free)++) = ((void *)datum);
```

Ie., the post-increment is acting on the `void**` (on which pointer arithmetic is valid), not the dereferenced `void*` (which is an lvalue and would be valid to post-increment - if pointer arithmetic were valid on `void*`).

Also note that as a language extension, GCC permits pointer arithmetic on `void*` (treating it similar to `char*`).

Comment: So this is why `*(__o->next_free)++ = 0;` will compile and the other cannot?  So the solution is to remove the `(void**)`?

Comment: @annoying_squid: yes to your first question.  Removing the `(void**)` will get rid of the error you're seeing now, but I can't answer the second question since I don't know the types of everything involved in the expression - or what the intent of the code is.

Comment: I would think that `*((void **)__o->next_free)++ = ((void *)datum);` and `*(__o->next_free)++ = ((void *)datum);` would do the same thing regardless of the cast.  But I should look into it just in case.

Comment: What is the actual type of `__o->next_free`?  You might want to simply things by using two separate expressions.  Something like (again - details depend on exactly what types are involved and what result you need from the expressions): `*__o->next_free = (void*)dataum; __o->next_free++;`  Keep in mind there is no performance penalty for breaking up that expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code, the `next_free` member is a `char *`, so what the code is trying to do is to store a pointer there and advancing to the next item. In particular, if you look at a bit of the code around, it's checking if `__o->next_free + sizeof (void *)` is beyond the chunk limit, so that makes it really clear what the code is trying to achieve.

We can just open-code it as a dereference followed by advancing to the next item:

```
 #define obstack_ptr_grow(OBSTACK,datum)                                \
 __extension__                                                          \
 ({ struct obstack *__o = (OBSTACK);                                    \
    if (__o->next_free + sizeof (void *) > __o->chunk_limit)            \
      _obstack_newchunk (__o, sizeof (void *));                         \
-   if (!__o->alloc_failed)                                             \
-     *((void **)__o->next_free)++ = ((void *)datum);                   \
+   if (!__o->alloc_failed) {                                           \
+     *((void **)__o->next_free) = ((void *)datum);                     \
+     __o->next_free += sizeof (void *);                                \
+   }                                                                   \
    (void) 0; })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe pointer math relative to a void pointer is undefined. Remember, incrementing a pointer means stepping it forward by the size of the thing it points to. What's the size of void? (Answer: void has no size, by definition.)

Addressing takes precedence over other operators, so what you're doing here is casting the value to (void **), dereferencing it to get (void *), and then trying to apply ++ to that. This may not be what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not seem to make any sense. At the first sight it looks like it was supposed to be

```
(*((void **)__o->next_free))++
```

Any postfix operator in C has higher precedence than any prefix operator. It means that postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`. So, in your original variant you are actually doing

```
*(((void **)__o->next_free)++)
```

I.e. you are indeed applying `++` to an rvalue - the result of the conversion to `void **`. It cannot possibly compile. The error message is right.

The `(*((void **)__o->next_free))++` version will not have the lvalue error and will compile (assuming the compiler supports `void *` arithmetic as a non-standard extension). But the fact that later `((void *)datum)` is assigned to the result of that expression makes it rather meaningless again (i.e. it will reintroduce the lvalue error through a different path).

Comment: I removed the (void**) and it compiled.  Do you think this was a good idea?

Comment: @annoying_squid: This question has no answer until you figure out what the original version was supposed to do.